# Can someone give me a full walkthrough of how py-script's <py-repl> tag works?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pyscript

I'm making a Python for medics tutorial website using PyScript and React: https://medicode-test.netlify.app/

However, I don't understand how the different parts of the `<py-repl>` tag work. I've been trying to just use it out of the box, but I would like to customise the design (especially that of the output/errors/not making new REPLs on execution/ having multi-line code pre-inserted etc).

I understand that the `<py-repl>` tag makes new HTML elements when the website loads - but (as I understand) this means I can't use CSS selectors on the newly created elements?

Can anyone give me a walkthrough of the deceptively simple:

```js
<py-repl id={`my-repl3`} auto-generate="true" std-out="output3" std-err="err-div3">
</py-repl>
<div id={`output3`} class=""></div>
<div id={`err-div3`}></div>
```

Comment: `<py-repl>` is a React Component that wraps [Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/), which loads an entire Python environment into the browser as a WASM package (basically CPython compiled with Emscripten). You don't need React _at all_ to use Pyodide or get an in-browser Python REPL [as they have a minimal demo that you can play with](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/console.html).

Comment: _"I understand that the `<py-repl>` tag makes new javascript when the website loads"_ - what do you mean by "makes new javascript"?

Comment: I'm using React as it's a personal project + useful for re-using components (initially made the tutorial on Google Colab - essentially mimicking their coding/text cells).

Comment: @Dai that was dumb language - edited to **html elements**

Comment: _"this means I can't use CSS selectors on the newly created elements?"_ - no, **you can**, but ideally you should use React's own styles/CSS features instead of forcing it using raw stylesheet selectors.

Comment: That sounds very promising but unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that